# Java SWT doesn't work outside eclipse

Tags: java, user-interface, jar, swt, runnable

i have a Java SWT Project, i want to export as a runnable Jar file.

Inside of eclipse it works well (JUNO) with no Problems.

After export (tried both ways [Runnable Jar File or jar File with manuel manifest]), the genereated Jar just shows a blank window.

(its a JFrame with SWT Widget).

Everything works until the Line:
"Display display = new Display();"

After that, i cant show anything on the window.
(tried it with JOptionPane Messages)...

What might be the problem?

Comment: Did you check your classpath? Do you get any errors when you run it from the console?

Comment: mixing up Swing and SWT? Bold move. First of all, I would try using only SWT if possible. Also, passing a little bit of code might make us able to help you more...

Comment: Ahh, forgot to start it from console:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display

Comment: Hmm, what can i do?
I added the swt.jar in manifest:
"Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/swt.jar 
Main-Class: start.Main

Comment: Ok, it works now :O
But just, when i start it from console...?!
It still fails with double click...
(Win7 x64)

Comment: Thank you, works now :)
Misstake was:
->old swt.jar (and 64bit, with 32bit JRE :D)